# Kotlin Global Variable Showing As Zero "0"

Tags: android, string, kotlin, global-variables, var

I am a complete beginner and have started to learn Kotlin via YouTube tutorials and Google searching for specifics.
When I was following a tutorial, he created three variables inside the `MainActivity` class as the following

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var firstName= "David"
var secondName= "Tal"
var age = 20

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

Next, he uses the created variables in a private function like this:

```
private fun nameRating(){
   if(firstName == secondName){
      Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"10/10", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }else{
      Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"5/10", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }}
```

I followed the example and recreated it in Android Studio, but the if condition triggered, and I thought it was weird. After debugging it turned out that both `firstName` and `secondName` are `"0"`. I thought the variables were supposed to be global, and it is confusing why it is not working because the `age` variable is correct.

If I am completely wrong on how this should work, any explanation/clarification on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends, are we seeing your whole code? If I copy what you posted above into an activity, and if I call just the nameRating function from inside onCreate, I get the expected values for all 3 variables. Change the "var" keywords to "val" for all 3 fields, and see if the Kotlin compiler complains. If it complains, it means that somewhere else  in your code you are changing those fields to a different value (except age, since that one is the same). And it might just happen that, said other code runs, and sets your first two variables to "0", before your nameRating() function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, Kotlin is not doing anything weird or magical behind your back in this case.

The `var` keyword in Kotlin means that you are declaring a variable, but the scope of that variable is not "global". The scope is the code block in which the variable is declared. In your case, you declared 3 variables in a class scope, so these are class variables and they can be accessed from anywhere inside the class `MainActivity`. Since they are also `public` (by default in Kotlin declarations are public, unless you specify a different access modifier, such as `private`, `protected` etc.), these 3 variables can also be accessed from outside the class (or from a subclass), as long as the calling code has a reference to an instance of this class. This works the same in Java, if something is public same access rules apply.

Since these are variables (their value can change) it also means that any code that has access to them, can also change their values. So the "weird" behavior that you are experiencing is likely due to some other part of code setting `firstName` and `secondName` to `"0"` before your `nameRating()` function is called, and that is why `firstName` and `secondName` are equal and the `if` condition evaluates to `true`.

In Android Studio, you can right-click on one of your variables and select "Find Usages". Search results will show up, and there you will see parts in code where other code might be changing the values of your variables. Hopefully that will shed some light on this behavior that you are seeing.